# How to make a button that sends data via Bluetooth as long as is being pressed Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I need to make an app which, when a button is pressed, a character is sent to Arduino via Bluetooth with a delay of 50ms. I'm new to Android and surfing on the internet I found this solution:

```
base_destra.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            sendData("d");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            sendData("10");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Where sendData is this:

```
private void sendData(String data){
    if(OutStream == null){
        return;
    }
    byte[] comando = data.getBytes();
    try {
        OutStream.write(comando);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Errore: comando non mandato",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I saw a tutorial on YouTube but although I copy-pasted the code shown, the app doesn't send anything.

PS: Arduino and the phone are correctly connected.

PPS: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Timer`. In the toggle button onClick method you can call `timedDataSender()` and in the button off method you can set `shouldCancel` `boolean` variable to `true` and the sending task should be finished. Here is a sample code:

```
/* A sendTimer is used to periodically send data */
private Timer sendTimer;
private Boolean shouldCancel = false;
private void timedDataSender(){

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendData("10");
                    }
                });


                if(shouldCancel)
                    cancel();

            }
        };

        sendTimer = new Timer("Timer");
        /* TimerTask, startDelay, period */
        sendTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,50);

    }
```